# Texture.loadFromFile decreased my fps.Should be 60 instead of 30fps

Tags: c++, sfml

When I start game fps is about 60 but on holding button "W" my fps decrease to 30.On release that button it became 60 again.This happens because line of code:
model->Load("img/characters.png", rec).

If I'll comment line like this "//" character gonna move smoothly with 60fps but w/o turning to top.

```
Entity *player;

void heroMovement()
{

if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W))
{
    sf::IntRect top(32, 224, 32, 32);

    this->player->Load("img/characters.png", top);

    calculateTileAnimation(0, 32, 64, top , this->player);

    velocity.y -= character_speed;

}

}
void calculateTileAnimation(int firstTile , int sizeTile , int 
lastTile,sf::IntRect rec , Entity *model)
{
    model->Load("img/characters.png", rec); // This line decreasing fps

    if (clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() < 0.3f)
    {
        rec.left += sizeTile;
        if (rec.left == lastTile)
            rec.left = firstTile;
        clock.restart();
    }
}


 void Load(std::string filename, sf::IntRect rec)
{
    this->texture->loadFromFile(filename, rec);
    this->setTexture(*this->texture);
}
```

Need to fix it , on holding button "w" character should be turned on top and move with 60fps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You load the textures from disk *on every keystroke*. Don't. Load the textures from disk at the start of your game (you probably know those loading screens) and store them in variables.

Then *use* them, for example in the `setTexture` method.

Comment: I got it:) Thank you for advice.